# TcpState from TcpClient

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.android

I'm looking for another way to get the TcpClient's state than the following:

```
var tcpState = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties()
                                 .GetActiveTcpConnections()
                                 .FirstOrDefault(x => x.LocalEndPoint == tcpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint)?.State;
```

The mono framework doesn't have a method implemented or something for some unknown reason.
This is the error I get when calling `GetActiveTcpConnections()`:

> The method or operation is not implemented. at System.Net.NetworkInformation.UnixIPGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections ()

The only other way I can think of is to create my own version of the `SystemIPGlobalProperties.cs` class, but I don't even know if it will work. Source of the class here [SystemIPGlobalProperties Source Code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/System/Net/NetworkInformation/SystemIPGlobalProperties.cs)

The reason is I want to determine if the connection is established or not before I try to write to it. There is another "filthy" way to get around this, that is to not check the state at all, wrap it in `try {} catch {}` and just try to write, if it breaks, assume that the connection dropped.

Comment: `netstat` command is a good starting point for unix & windows machine. But you will need to parse the output..